# Table Manipulation Tracking

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has multiple scripts/sites interacting with it in terms of updating/inserting new data.

Since there is not one interface for doing this, I would like to some how track what is happening on a daily basis in MySQL.

What kinds of built in features does MySQL have for tracking changes?

For example:

An update command is performed on a column named 'num_images'.

I would like to track this change in another table that would state what column was changed and what it was changed to.

What is the most efficient way to track a table? What should I be reading up on to put a type of tracker on a table to look for these changes?

Comment: This is more administration oriented than development, so it might be better suited to ServerFault.  I found this: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/SimpleDataAuditing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me it would be fairly easily to use triggers to achieve the kind of reporting you are looking for. I use trigger in several project to keep a revision history on records.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Found a good newbie tutorial on it here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/